# Issue on Install Dual Boot Android and Ubuntu Touch on Nexus-4

Tags: android, ubuntu, installation

I trying to install Ubuntu on Nexus-4 to follow https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation . But when I execute **./dualboot.sh FULL** it's responding **Connect device to install Ubuntu installer to.** . I checked with adb device, it showing device online.

**More on:  According [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) ..adb wait-for-device** wait untill device not get online. But anyway I able to access adb shell with log. That's mean device online. Then why it not respoding device status..Any idea/suggestion, if I am missing something??

Answer (score -1):

USB-Debugging must be enabled. Therefor you have to tab Buildno several times until you are a developer. Afterwards go into the developer menu and enable usb-debugging